# rails jquery mobile redirects to wrong url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery-mobile

In a rails 4 jQuery mobile application, after updating a record, my controller redirects to the index (list) page but the browser url is show while the view is index.

I think the answer is to turn off Ajax but I can't figure out how to incorporate the jQuery mobile directive data-ajax="false" into the rails form helper.

```
<%= form_for (@user) do |f| %>
```

browser:

```
http://localhost:3000/users/1
```

view in browser :index.html.erb

routes.rb:

```
resources :users
```

controller:

```
def update
  respond_to do |format|
    if @user.update(user_params)
      format.html { redirect_to users_path,
                  notice: "User #{@user.user_name} was successfully updated." }
    else
      format.html { render action: 'edit' }
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to add the data-url directive into my layout.

```
<div data-role="page" id="home" data-url="<%= request.path %>">
```

Answer (score 0):

That works well by @markhorrocks answer. And my solution is like you. Just add a instance variable in controller, like `@data_url = '/room'`, and add 
`ruby
<div data-role="page" id="home" data-url="<%= @data_url %>">`